# how to compare spanish character in Lua

Tags: lua

I have to compare the contents of a lua variable with a string having spanish characters e.g. 
if  is equal to bisci**ó**n. 
if myvar = "bisci**ó**n" does not work when myvar contains the same value.
I could not find anything relevant to this in Lua documentation except setting the locales at http://www.lua.org/pil/20.html. However, this also does not seem to work.

How do I test for equality (If it matters, I am using ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: [Lua Unicode](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode) may be of some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a problem of Lua itself.

```
> print("bisción" == "bisción")
true
```

Perhaps there is a discrepancy between the character encoding used by your source code editor, and by your data sources. Lua makes the compare operation at byte level. It's enough to have the Lua source file encoded with UTF-8, for example, and the data loaded from a file with UTF-16 encoding, and the compare fails.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. Lua file was encoded as iso-8859-1. I used iconv to convert to UTF8. After that it started working. Thanks for your much needed help